# android restore RecyclerView scroll position after updating data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Here I have a `RecyclerView` that is populated by `Room` and `LiveData`. in every item of the `RecyclerView` I have a `CheckBox` that should update a boolean value in the row of my database. So the problem is when the `Database` is updated the `RecyclerVie` will have to draw every item again so the scroll will be at top. The question is how to restore the scroll after the data is updated.

the code is shown below:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks_list, container, false)

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_task_time) as FloatingActionButton

    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    taskListViewModel.tasksListLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let { taskList->
            taskListViewModel.tasksList = taskList
            this.recyclerView.adapter = TasksListAdapter(taskList)
        }
    })
}

private inner class TaskHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    private lateinit var id: UUID
    // the other views
    private val isDone = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.tasks_done)


    init {
        
        isDone.setOnClickListener {
            taskListViewModel.updateTask((it as CheckBox).isChecked, id)
        }
    }

    fun bind(itemHolder: TasksItemHolder){
        this.id = itemHolder.id
        isDone.isChecked = itemHolder.done
    }

}

private inner class TasksListAdapter(var taskList: List<TasksItemHolder>): RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskHolder {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_list_item, parent, false)
        return TaskHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(taskList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return taskList.size
    }
```

EDIT:

so i have tried adding a new inner class that extends the recycler view on scroll listener and setting it to my recycler's on scroll listener. but the same problem triggers that i cant restore the scroll before the update because the last state of scroll is when every thing is updated and scroll is on top.

any help would be appreciated even if it doesn't work.

EDIT2:
with advise of two of the friends that they said dont create adapter every time that the live data is observed i have changed the code so i have one adapter that i can just put a list in it and it works perfectly and hold the position of the scroll after the update. although another problem has accrued and thats when i close the application and open it again, sometimes the list is empty and i have to close and reopen the fragment to see the list. and i dont get any error about the recycler or adapter even if it opens empty.
this is refined code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    taskAdapter = TasksListAdapter()
    if (taskListViewModel.tasksList != null){
        taskAdapter.taskList = taskListViewModel.tasksList!!
    }

    date = arguments?.getString(DATE_KEY) as String

    taskListViewModel.loadDate(date)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks_list, container, false)

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.adapter = taskAdapter
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    taskListViewModel.tasksListLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it?.let { taskList->
            if (taskListViewModel.tasksList != taskList) {
                taskListViewModel.tasksList = taskList
                this.taskAdapter.taskList = taskListViewModel.tasksList!!
            }
        }
    })
}


private inner class TaskHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener{

    private lateinit var taskId: UUID
    private val taskIsDone = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.tasks_done)


    init {
        
        taskIsDone.setOnClickListener {
            taskListViewModel.updateTask((it as CheckBox).isChecked, taskId)
        }
    }

    fun bind(itemHolder: TasksItemHolder){
        this.taskId = itemHolder.id
        taskIsDone.isChecked = itemHolder.done
    }

}

private inner class TasksListAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskHolder>(){
    var taskList: List<TasksItemHolder> = mutableListOf()
        set(value){field = value}
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskHolder {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_list_item, parent, false)
        return TaskHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(taskList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return taskList.size
    }
```

**THANKS AGAIN TO BOTH @Michiel AND @ChhatrasalSinghBundela**

so apparently i had to notify changes and it works perfect now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the adapter is recreated every time the data updates. Take a look at [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter).

This is a subclass of Adapter, which has `submitList(List)` to update the result. In there there's an example how to create the adapter once and push `taskList` very time it changes.

Comment: yes i know that the adapter is recreating the items again. and my adapter is not list adapter it is a custom adapter as it extends recyclerview adapter, not that it changes functionality. although  i want to store the state for scroll view so after having the update in recyclerview i can set it to the stored again and i dont go to the top of my list after every checkbox click

Comment: @NimaKhajehpour Whether it is `ListAdapter` or custom adapter which extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`, you should avoid creating new adapters on every observe. If your specific data changes on `CheckBox` selection then you should not create a new adapter, you can update the existing adapter.
For the answer, the best you can do with current implementation is you can register `addOnScrollListener()`.

Comment: On `onScrolled()` event calculate either first visible item or last visible item position and store in the class level variable and on every new adapter creation check the variable for last position, if the last position exists then scroll to that position. This concept will resolve your issue, but might create new issues like `IndexOutOfBound` exception or might not result as expected position because of any change in the item position. So its best to create adapter only once and you can update the list on every observe.

Comment: no new adapter is made every time, there is one adapter that takes care of the observable.
i tried the onscroll listener for my recycler but because i need to extend recycler in my fragment to use it i cant have it. (i have extended fragment) so that was not possible to do for me

Comment: @ChhatrasalSinghBundela and even if i add an inner class and make my own scroll listener that extends the recycler views on scroll listener it doesnt work because if it scrolls up at update time the last scroll will be top of the list

Comment: Not true, every time `taskListViewModel.tasksListLiveData` changes a new adapter is created in the second line of the callback. Also, apart from if it's problematic right now, `taskListViewModel.tasksList = taskList` should not exist in a fragment.

Comment: @Michiel so the reason for that is: 1st i have a repositry that takes care of my DAO and i take the instance of my repository in my view model so then with help of live data i can have every thing processed in background thread. and second of all because it is live data and it needs to be observed and the observing happens in the background and also it needs to have a instance of lifecycle owner it should be observed in the fragment. so for it being in the background thread it can have delay for observing and it doesnt effect the main thread.

Comment: if i put the adapter that is observed out of the observable it would not give the list to the adapter at the right time because of the delay of the background thread and the list will be empty so i have to give the list to the adapter immediately after its observed.
if there is another way that works better feel free to tell me it would be so much appreciated.

Comment: and about having the ```taskViewModel.taskList = taskList``` is that so i can store the list to my view model not the fragment so when the background process is done i can have the list in my view model and i dont have to observe my live data over and over again.

Comment: and correct me if i'm wrong, i have the observe in my ```onViewCreated``` that will be called once upon start of a fragment, so technically the adapter is being made once when the ```onViewCreated``` is called.

Comment: thanks a lot to both of you guy. you helped alot